# find command works on prompt, not in bash script - pass multiple arguments by variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, quoting

I've searched around questions with similar issues but haven't found one that quite fits my situation.

Below is a very brief script that demonstrates the problem I'm facing:

```
#!/bin/bash

includeString="-wholename './public_html/*' -o -wholename './config/*'"
find . \( $includeString \) -type f -mtime -7 -print
```

Basically, we need to search inside a folder, but only in certain of its subfolders. In my longer script, includeString gets built from an array. For this demo, I kept things simple.

Basically, when I run the script, it doesn't find anything. No errors, but also no hits. If I manually run the find command, it works. If I remove ( $includeString ) it also works, though obviously it doesn't limit itself to the folders I want.

So why would the same command work from the command line but not from the bash script? What is it about passing in $includeString that way that causes it to fail?

Comment: Your example command expands to this: `find . ( -wholename './public_html/*' -o -wholename './config/*' ) -type f -mtime -7 -print`.  Q: Is that what you want?  Does it work when you copy/paste verbatim to the command line?

Comment: Why are you using a directory of `.` and then filtering with `-wholename` instead of just using `find ./public_html ./config ... -type f -mtime 7 -print`?

Comment: BTW, the underlying issue here is covered in BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an issue with how the shell handles variable expansion.  In your script:

```
includeString="-wholename './public_html/*' -o -wholename './config/*'"
find . \( $includeString \) -type f -mtime -7 -print
```

This results in `find` looking for files where `-wholename` matches the *literal string* `'./public_html/*'`.  That is, a *filename* that contains single quotes.  Since you don't have any whitespace in your paths, the easiest solution here would be to just drop the single quotes:

```
includeString="-wholename ./public_html/* -o -wholename ./config/*"
find . \( $includeString \) -type f -mtime -7 -print
```

Unfortunately, you'll probably get bitten by wildcard expansion here (the shell will attempt to expand the wildcards before `find` sees them).

But as Etan pointed out in his comment, this appears to be needlessly complex; you can simply do:

```
find ./public_html ./config -type f -mtime -7 -print
```

Comment: When I remove the single quotes, I get this error: _find: paths must precede expression: ./public_html/uploads_ but when I follow the other approach - just including the paths - it works. I thought I had tried this approach already and it didn't work, but evidently I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Good hint re single quotes becoming part of the filename, but the issue that @ChrisRoberts just pointed out is that _unquoted_ use of `$includeString` makes the words in it subject to up-front _pathname expansion_ by the _shell_, which breaks the `find` command (if there are at least two matches.)

Comment: P.S.: In other words: it's generally impossible to _robustly_ pass multiple arguments via a single string variable.

Comment: Right, and this is why trying to deal with multiple levels of quoting is tricky. You would probably solve it with `eval`, but I think the solution that discards both quoting and wildcards is better.

Comment: Arrays are the most robust solution, followed by `xargs`, if you must remain POSIX-compliant; given the latter, `eval` can always be avoided (so as to avoid its security issues).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a list of arguments and expand it later, the correct form to do that with is an array, not a string:

```
includeArgs=( -wholename './public_html/*' -o -wholename './config/*' )
find . '(' "${includeArgs[@]}" ')' -type f -mtime -7 -print
```

This is covered in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: + for concision and the link, but I hope I didn't slave in the kitchen all day for naught.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: As Etan points out in a comment, the better solution in *this* case may be to reformulate the `find` command, but passing multiple arguments via variable(s) is a technique worth exploring in general.</sup>

**tl;dr**:

The problem is **not specific to `find`**, but to **how the *shell* parses command lines**.

- **Quote characters embedded in variable values** are **treated as *literals***: They are neither recognized as *argument-boundary delimiters* nor are they *removed* after parsing, so you ***cannot* use a string variable with embedded quoting** to pass ***multiple* arguments** simply **by directly using it as part of a command**.
- To **robustly pass multiple arguments stored in a variable**,

  - use ***array* variables** in shells that support them (`bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`) - see below.
  - otherwise, **for POSIX compliance, use `xargs`** - see below.

---

**Robust solutions**:

Note: The solutions assume presence of the following *script*, let's call it `echoArgs`, which prints the arguments passed to it in diagnostic form:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for arg; do     # loop over all arguments
  echo "[$arg]" # print each argument enclosed in [] so as to see its boundaries
done
```

Further, assume that the **equivalent of the following command is to be executed**:

```
echoArgs one 'two three' '*' last  # note the *literal* '*' - no globbing
```

with **all arguments *but the last* passed by *variable***.

Thus, the expected outcome is:

```
[one]
[two three]
[*]
[last]
```

- **Using an array variable (`bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`):**

```sh
# Assign the arguments to *individual elements* of *array* args.
# The resulting array looks like this: [0]="one" [1]="two three" [2]="*"
args=( one 'two three' '*' )

# Safely pass these arguments - note the need to *double-quote* the array reference:
echoArgs "${args[@]}" last
```

- **Using `xargs` - a *POSIX-compliant* alternative:**

POSIX utility `xargs`, unlike the shell itself, *is* capable of recognized quoted strings embedded in a string:

```sh
# Store the arguments as *single string* with *embedded quoting*.
args="one 'two three' '*'"

# Let *xargs* parse the embedded quoted strings correctly.
# Note the need to double-quote $args.
echo "$args" | xargs -J {} echoArgs {} last
```

Note that `{}` is a freely chosen placeholder that allows you to control where in the resulting command line the arguments provided by `xargs` go.
If all `xarg`-provided arguments go *last*, there is no need to use `-J` at all.

<sup>For the sake of completeness: `eval` can also be used to parse quoted strings embedded in another string, but `eval` is a security risk: arbitrary commands could end up getting executed; given the safe solutions discussed above, there is no need to use `eval`.</sup>

<sup>Finally, Charles Duffy mentions another safe alternative in a comment, which, however, requires more coding: encapsulate the command to invoke in a *shell function*, pass the variable arguments as separate arguments to the function, then manipulate the all-arguments array `$@` inside the function to supplement the fixed arguments (using `set`), and invoke the command with `"$@"`.</sup>

---

**Explanation of the shell's string-handling issues involved:**

- When you **assign a string to a *variable***, **embedded quote characters become *part of the string***:

  ```
  var='one "two three" *'
  ```
- `$var` now *literally* contains `one "two three" *`, i.e., the following **4** - instead of the intended 3 - words, separated by a space each:

  - `one`
  - `"two`-- `"` is part of the *word itself*!
  - `three"`-- `"` is part of the *word itself*!
  - `*`
- When you use `$var` *unquoted* as part of an argument list, the **above breakdown into 4 words is exactly what the shell does *initially*** - a process called ***word splitting***. <sup>Note that if you were to *double-quote* the variable reference (`"$var"`), the entire string would always become a *single* argument.</sup>

  - Because `$var` is *expanded* to its value, one of the so-called [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), **the shell does NOT attempt to recognize embedded quotes inside that value as marking argument boundaries** - this only works with quote characters specified *literally*, as a *direct* part of the command line (assuming these quote characters aren't themselves quoted).
  - Similarly, only such directly specified quote characters are removed by the shell before passing the enclosed string to the command being invoked - a process called ***quote removal***.
- However, the shell **additionally applies pathname expansion** (globbing) to the resulting 4 words, so any of the words that happen to match filenames will expand to the matching filenames.
- In short: **the quote characters in `$var`'s value are neither recognized as *argument-boundary delimiters* nor are they *removed* after parsing.** Additionally, the words in `$var`'s value are subject to **pathname expansion**.
- This means that the only way to pass multiple arguments is to leave them *unquoted* inside the variable value (and also leave the *reference* to that variable *unquoted*), which:

  - won't work with values with embedded spaces or shell metacharacters
  - *invariably* subjects the values to pathname expansion

Comment: I'm personally wary of recommending xargs without GNU extensions `-0` or `-d` (both of which, obviously, prevent the behavior it's intentionally being used for here) given how easy it is to use unsafely by mistake, but there's a lot of great advice and explanation in this answer. I'm curious -- how long were you working on this? Looks like it was as yet unposted when my much-pithier answer went in.

Comment: I appreciate the compliment, @CharlesDuffy. I figured `xargs` was preferable to `eval`, security-wise (and I only recommended it for when arrays aren't available). I didn't keep track of how long I worked on this, but a good couple of hours, I'd say (which included my own experiments and deepening my own understanding).

Comment: One other option for pure-POSIX shells, by the way, is encapsulating code inside a function and overriding or manipulating `"$@"` therein. Granted, it's only _one_ array (within each function's scope), but that's often enough.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Manipulating `$@` inside a function probably goes beyond the scope of this answer, but I've added it as a footnote (of sorts); thanks.